# Почему видео загружается не в группу, а в мои видеозаписи?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
vk_key = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

def group_video(group_id):
    video = vk_key.method("video.save",{"name": "hello", "description": " world"})
    b = requests.post(video["upload_url"], files={'video_file': open('../groups/multipro/video_files/185999', 'rb')}).json()
    post = "video{}_{}".format(b["owner_id"], b["video_id"])
    
    vk_key.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": group_id, "attachment": post})
group_video(-118191956)
```

Comment: Потому что вы нигде не указали, что его надо загружать именно в группу

Comment: Сможете поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
video = vk_key.method("video.save",{"name": "hello", "description": " world;","group_id": "118191956"})
```